# Initializing tensorflow Variable with an array larger than 2GB

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to initialize a tensorflow `Variable` with pre-trained `word2vec` embeddings.

I have the following code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from gensim import models

model = models.Word2Vec.load_word2vec_format('GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin', binary=True)
X = model.syn0

embeddings = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform(X.shape, minval=-0.1, maxval=0.1), trainable=False)

sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())

sess.run(embeddings.assign(X))
```

And I am receiving the following error:

```
ValueError: Cannot create an Operation with a NodeDef larger than 2GB.
```

The array (`X`) I am trying to assign is of shape `(3000000, 300)` and its size is 3.6GB.

I am getting the same error if I try `tf.convert_to_tensor(X)` as well.

I know that it fails due to the fact that the array is larger than 2GB. However, I do not know how to assign an array larger than 2GB to a tensorflow `Variable`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The easiest solution is to feed_dict'ing it into a placeholder node that you use to tf.assign to the variable.

```
X = tf.Variable([0.0])
place = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(3000000, 300))
set_x = X.assign(place)
# set up your session here....
sess.run(set_x, feed_dict={place: model.syn0})
```

As Joshua Little noted in a separate answer, you can also use it in the initializer:

```
X = tf.Variable(place)    # place as defined above
...
init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
... create sess ...
sess.run(init, feed_dict={place: model.syn0})
```

Comment: `X.assign(place)` needs to be `tf.assign(X, place, validate_shape=False)`, or TensorFlow will complain that you're changing the tensor's shape. Other than that, this works.

Comment: Thank you - updated the answer to include that + mrry's comment below, by setting the shape of the placeholder.

Comment: for more info there is a good description of how to do this in the documentation under [preloaded data](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/how_tos/reading_data/index.html#preloaded-data) and a full working example on how to use a placeholder and a variable to preload MNIST training inputs [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r0.7/tensorflow/examples/how_tos/reading_data/fully_connected_preloaded_var.py)

Comment: Also `tf.initialize_all_variables()` needs to be `tf.global_variables_initializer()` because of it gives warning that `initialize_all_variables()` function is deprecated.

Answer (score 19):

It seems like the only option is to use a placeholder. The cleanest way I can find is to initialize to a placeholder directly:

```py
X_init = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(3000000, 300))
X = tf.Variable(X_init)
# The rest of the setup...
sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables(), feed_dict={X_init: model.syn0})
```

Comment: Note that you can also set the optional shape argument when you call `tf.placeholder()` and then you don't need `validate_shape=False` (and you get better shape inference in the rest of your program!).

Comment: @mrry, Oh, that's right. Thanks. I've added that to the answer.

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from gensim import models

model = models.KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format('./GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin', binary=True)
X = model.syn0

embeddings = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform(X.shape, minval=-0.1, maxval=0.1), trainable=False)

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
embeddings.load(model.syn0, sess)
```