# ensemble model with different inputs (Expected to see 2 array(s))

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, ensemble-learning

I have trained 2 models.

First model is UNet:

```
print(model_unet.summary())

__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_4 (InputLayer)            (None, 128, 128, 1)  0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_26 (Conv2D)              (None, 128, 128, 32) 320         input_4[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_27 (Conv2D)              (None, 128, 128, 32) 9248        conv2d_26[0][0]  
.....
.....
conv2d_44 (Conv2D)              (None, 128, 128, 1)  33          zero_padding2d_4[0][0]           
==================================================================================================
Total params: 7,846,081
Trainable params: 7,846,081
Non-trainable params: 0
```

Second is ResNet:

```
print(model_resnet.summary())

__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_3 (InputLayer)            (None, 128, 128, 3)  0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv1_pad (ZeroPadding2D)       (None, 134, 134, 3)  0           input_3[0][0]                    
....
....
conv2d_25 (Conv2D)              (None, 128, 128, 3)  99          zero_padding2d_3[0][0]           
==================================================================================================
Total params: 24,186,915
Trainable params: 24,133,795
Non-trainable params: 53,120
```

The UNet has 1 channel (gray) and the ResNet has 3 channels.

Then, I am trying to create an ensemble model:

```
def ensemble(models, models_input):

    outputs = [model(models_input[idx]) for idx, model in enumerate(models)]
    x = Average()(outputs)

    model_inputs = [model for model in models_input]
    model = Model(model_inputs, x)

    return model

models = [model_unet, model_resnet]
models_input = [Input((128,128,1)), Input((128,128, 3))]

ensemble_model = ensemble(models, models_input)
```

When I try to predict on validation data:

```
pred_val = ensemble_model.predict(X_val)
```

I am receiving the error:

```
Error when checking model input: the list of Numpy arrays that you are passing to your model is not the size the model expected. Expected to see 2 array(s), but instead got the following list of 1 arrays: [array([[[[0.46755977],
         [0.52268691],
         [0.52766109],
         ....

X_val.shape is : (800, 128, 128, 1)
```

I think the problem is the channels but I don't know how to overcome this.

Comment: Can you try using `pred_val = ensemble_model.predict(X_val[0])`

Comment: @Bazingaa:It gives me exactly the same error.

Comment: @George You have defined two input layers for the model but you are giving it only one input array. How is it supposed to feed the other one related to resnet?

Comment: @today:Hmm..Do you mean I must use this? `ensemble_model.predict([X_val, X_val])`.So, for each model, give the array?I didn't know that.But, it works!You just have to alter X_val in order to have 3 channels!

Comment: @today:If you want make it an answer please!Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your training data are grayscale images and considering that your ResNet model takes as input RGB images, then you should ask yourself how do you want to go from grayscale to RGB? One answer is to repeat the grayscale image 3 times to get the RBG image. Then you can easily define a model with **one** input layer that takes your grayscale images and feed them accordingly to the models you have defined:

```
from keras import backend as K

input_image = Input(shape=(128,128,1))

unet_out = model_unet(input_image)
rgb_image = Lambda(lambda x: K.repeat_elements(x, 3, -1))(input_image)
resnet_out = model_resnet(rgb_image)

output = Average()([unet_out, resnet_out])

ensemble_model = Model(input_image, output)
```

Then you can easily call `predict` with **one** input array:

```
pred_val = ensemble_model.predict(X_val)
```

One alternative to this solution is to go with the solution you have used in your question. However, you first need to convert your images from grayscale to RGB and then pass both of the arrays to `predict` method:

```
X_val_rgb = np.repeat(X_val, 3, -1)

pred_val = ensemble_model.predict([X_val, X_val_rgb])
```

Comment: Ok, thanks!But, if I try to use `np.repeat` it gives me memory error (18000 is the size of test data).I tried to use `tf.image.grayscale_to_rgb(X_test,name=None)` but still the same.I also looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35394103/initializing-tensorflow-variable-with-an-array-larger-than-2gb) but still the same.Do you think `K.repeat_elements` is more memory efficient?

Comment: @George `K.repeat_elements` is used inside the model. If you want to use your own solution, you need to prepare the data **before** feeding it to the model. Either you should increase your memory size or convert image in batches and do the prediction using [`predict_on_batch`](https://keras.io/models/model/#predict_on_batch). You can also define a generator and use [`predict_generator`](https://keras.io/models/model/#predict_generator) instead. However, I will go with the solution I suggested myself because I think it is more logical to have one input layer.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot!I had in my mind the predict generator, I will try that. (upv)